# U-Net: A TensorFlow model

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, tensorflow

## What I want to know

I am writing a ML model called U-Net with Python (and TensorFlow). My question is not about the machine learning or Tensorflow, I want to know the best structure of the code.

I write some code as my hobby and I've never written code as work, so I do not know what is the "good" code.

## My code

I made two files

- main.py
- model.py

The main.py has functions that load data and pass them to the model in model.py. The model.py has a class that represent the ML model and it contains not only the model structure but also a method to train.

The main process of these code is the training method in the model.py, so in main.py, I call this method from the model.py. I feel that this code structure is not correct, that is, I think the main process (training method) should be contained in the main.py, not in the model.py.

I want some advice how I should (or not) change my code.

main.py

```py
import argparse
import os
import glob
import random
import math

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

import model

def get_parser():
  """
  Set hyper parameters for training UNet.
  """
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('-e', '--epoch', type=int, default=100)
  parser.add_argument('-lr', '--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.0001)
  parser.add_argument('-tr', '--train_rate', type=float, default=0.8, help='ratio of training data')
  parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch_size', type=int, default=20)
  parser.add_argument('-l2', '--l2', type=float, default=0.05, help='L2 regularization')

  return parser

def load_data(image_dir, seg_dir, n_class, train_val_rate, onehot=True):
  """
  load images and segmented images.
  Parameters
  ==========
  image_dir: string 
    the directory of the raw images.
  seg_dir: string
    the directory of the segmented images.
  n_class: int
    the number of classes
  train_val_rate: float
    the ratio of training data to the validation data
  onehot: bool
  Returns
  =======
  the tuple.((training image, training segmented image), (validation image, validation segmented image))
  training/validation (segmented) images are the list of np.ndarray whose shape is (128, 128, 3) (row image)
  and (128, 128, n_class) (segmented image)
  """
  row_img = []
  segmented_img = []
  images = os.listdir(image_dir)
  random.shuffle(images)
  for idx, img in enumerate(images):
    if img.endswith('.png') or img.endswith('.jpg'):
      split_name = os.path.splitext(img)
      img = Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, img))
      if seg_dir != '':
        seg = Image.open(os.path.join(seg_dir, split_name[0] + '-seg' + split_name[1]))
        seg = seg.resize((128, 128)) 
        seg = np.asarray(seg, dtype=np.int16)
      else:
        seg = None

      img = img.resize((128, 128))
      img = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.float32)
      img, seg = preprocess(img, seg, n_class, onehot=onehot)
      row_img.append(img)
      segmented_img.append(seg)

  train_data = row_img[:int(len(row_img)*train_val_rate)], segmented_img[:int(len(row_img)*train_val_rate)]
  validation_data = row_img[int(len(row_img) * train_val_rate):], segmented_img[int(len(row_img) * train_val_rate):]

  return train_data, validation_data


def generate_data(input_images, teacher_images, batch_size):
  """
  generate the pair of the raw image and segmented image.
  Parameters
  ========== 
  inputs_images: list of the np.array
  teacher_image: list of the np.array or None
  batch_size: int
  Returns
  =======
  """
  batch_num = math.ceil(len(input_images) / batch_size)
  input_images = np.array_split(input_images, batch_num)
  if np.any(teacher_images == None):
    teacher_images = np.zeros(batch_num)
  else:
    teacher_images = np.array_split(teacher_images, batch_num)

  for i in range(batch_num):
    yield input_images[i], teacher_images[i]


def preprocess(img, seg, n_class, onehot):
  if onehot and seg is not None:
    identity = np.identity(n_class, dtype=np.int16) 
    seg = identity[seg]

  return img / 255.0, seg

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = get_parser().parse_args()
  unet = model.UNet(classes=2)
  unet.train(parser)
```

model.py

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import main

class UNet:
  def __init__(self, classes):
    self.IMAGE_DIR = './dataset/raw_images'
    self.SEGMENTED_DIR = './dataset/segmented_images'
    self.VALIDATION_DIR = './dataset/validation'
    self.classes = classes
    self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 3]) 
    self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.int16, [None, 128, 128, self.classes])
    self.is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

  @staticmethod
  def conv2d(
    inputs, filters, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu, l2_reg=None, 
    momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.001, is_training=False,
    ):
    """
    convolutional layer. If the l2_reg is a float number, L2 regularization is imposed.

    Parameters
    ----------
      inputs: tf.Tensor
      filters: Non-zero positive integer
        The number of the filter 
      activation: 
        The activation function. The default is tf.nn.relu
      l2_reg: None or float
        The strengthen of the L2 regularization
      is_training: tf.bool
        The default is False. If True, the batch normalization layer is added.
      momentum: float
        The hyper parameter of the batch normalization layer
      epsilon: float
        The hyper parameter of the batch normalization layer
    Returns
    -------
      layer: tf.Tensor
    """
    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=l2_reg) if l2_reg is not None else None
    layer = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=inputs,
      filters=filters,
      kernel_size=kernel_size,
      padding='SAME',
      activation=activation,
      kernel_regularizer=regularizer
    )

    if is_training is not None:
      layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=layer,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=momentum,
        epsilon=epsilon,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training=is_training
      )

    return layer

  @staticmethod
  def trans_conv(inputs, filters, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_size=2, strides=2, l2_reg=None):
    """
    transposed convolution layer.
    Parameters
    ---------- 
      inputs: tf.Tensor
      filters: int 
        the number of the filter
      activation: 
        the activation function. The default function is the ReLu.
      kernel_size: int
        the kernel size. Default = 2
      strides: int
        strides. Default = 2
      l2_reg: None or float 
        the strengthen of the L2 regularization.
    Returns
    -------
      layer: tf.Tensor
    """
    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=l2_reg) if l2_reg is not None else None

    layer = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
      inputs=inputs,
      filters=filters,
      kernel_size=kernel_size,
      strides=strides,
      kernel_regularizer=regularizer
    )

    return layer

  @staticmethod
  def pooling(inputs):
    return tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=inputs, pool_size=2, strides=2)


  def UNet(self, is_training, l2_reg=None):
    """
    UNet structure.
    Parameters
    ----------
      l2_reg: None or float
        The strengthen of the L2 regularization.
      is_training: tf.bool
        Whether the session is for training or validation.
    Returns
    -------
      outputs: tf.Tensor
    """
    conv1_1 = self.conv2d(self.X, filters=64, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    conv1_2 = self.conv2d(conv1_1, filters=64, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    pool1 = self.pooling(conv1_2)

    conv2_1 = self.conv2d(pool1, filters=128, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    conv2_2 = self.conv2d(conv2_1, filters=128, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    pool2 = self.pooling(conv2_2)

    conv3_1 = self.conv2d(pool2, filters=256, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    conv3_2 = self.conv2d(conv3_1, filters=256, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    pool3 = self.pooling(conv3_2)

    conv4_1 = self.conv2d(pool3, filters=512, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    conv4_2 = self.conv2d(conv4_1, filters=512, l2_reg=l2_reg, is_training=is_training)
    pool4 = self.pooling(conv4_2)

    conv5_1 = self.conv2d(pool4, filters=1024, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    conv5_2 = self.conv2d(conv5_1, filters=1024, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    concat1 = tf.concat([conv4_2, self.trans_conv(conv5_2, filters=512, l2_reg=l2_reg)], axis=3)

    conv6_1 = self.conv2d(concat1, filters=512, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    conv6_2 = self.conv2d(conv6_1, filters=512, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    concat2 = tf.concat([conv3_2, self.trans_conv(conv6_2, filters=256, l2_reg=l2_reg)], axis=3)

    conv7_1 = self.conv2d(concat2, filters=256, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    conv7_2 = self.conv2d(conv7_1, filters=256, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    concat3 = tf.concat([conv2_2, self.trans_conv(conv7_2, filters=128, l2_reg=l2_reg)], axis=3)

    conv8_1 = self.conv2d(concat3, filters=128, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    conv8_2 = self.conv2d(conv8_1, filters=128, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    concat4 = tf.concat([conv1_2, self.trans_conv(conv8_2, filters=64, l2_reg=l2_reg)], axis=3)

    conv9_1 = self.conv2d(concat4, filters=64, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    conv9_2 = self.conv2d(conv9_1, filters=64, l2_reg=l2_reg)
    outputs = self.conv2d(conv9_2, filters=self.classes, kernel_size=1, activation=None)

    return outputs

  def train(self, parser):
    """
    training operation
    argument of this function are given by functions in main.py
    Parameters
    ----------
      parser: 
        the paser that has some options
    """
    epoch = parser.epoch
    l2 = parser.l2
    batch_size = parser.batch_size
    train_val_rate = parser.train_rate

    output = self.UNet(l2_reg=l2, is_training=self.is_training)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=self.y, logits=output))
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
      train_ops = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(parser.learning_rate).minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=100)
    all_train, all_val = main.load_data(self.IMAGE_DIR, self.SEGMENTED_DIR, n_class=2, train_val_rate=train_val_rate)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      init.run()
      for e in range(epoch):
        data = main.generate_data(*all_train, batch_size)
        val_data = main.generate_data(*all_val, len(all_val[0]))
        for Input, Teacher in data:
          sess.run(train_ops, feed_dict={self.X: Input, self.y: Teacher, self.is_training: True})
          ls = loss.eval(feed_dict={self.X: Input, self.y: Teacher, self.is_training: None})
          for val_Input, val_Teacher in val_data:
            val_loss = loss.eval(feed_dict={self.X: val_Input, self.y: val_Teacher, self.is_training: None})

        print(f'epoch #{e + 1}, loss = {ls}, val loss = {val_loss}')
        if e % 100 == 0:
          saver.save(sess, f"./params/model_{e + 1}epochs.ckpt")

      self.validation(sess, output)

  def validation(self, sess, output):
    val_image = main.load_data(self.VALIDATION_DIR, '', n_class=2, train_val_rate=1)[0]
    data = main.generate_data(*val_image, batch_size=1)
    for Input, _ in data:
      result = sess.run(output, feed_dict={self.X: Input, self.is_training: None}) 
      break

    result = np.argmax(result[0], axis=2)
    ident = np.identity(3, dtype=np.int8)
    result = ident[result]*255

    plt.imshow((Input[0]*255).astype(np.int16))
    plt.imshow(result, alpha=0.2)
    plt.show()
```

The entire code are in my GitHub repository (https://github.com/Hayashi-Yudai/ML_models)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- This is clean code for a hobbyist. ML code in particular can end up being a procedural mess, just carrying out one imported function after another, but this is quite good.
- It's great that you have docstrings with explanations of the arguments, but the explanations of the functions/methods themselves are a little sparse. The odd comment would help a lot too.
- Try to follow PEP8. It's the standard style for all Python code and is generally followed by all Python programmers (4 spaces for indent, 2 spaces between functions, etc).
- Immediately I see that you're importing `model` in `main` and `main` in `model`. Imports should follow a hierarchy with no cycles. i.e. if A imports from B imports from C, C should never import from A, but it's ok if A imports directly from C.
- Typically, a file called `main`, `run`, `execute` or whatever will import other worker functions from elsewhere, then handle calling them in the correct way. This often means argument parsing is contained in the `main` file but not a lot else. Given that you have a lot of logic for generating and sorting data, I would separate this out.
- When comparing a `var` to `None`, use the idioms `var is None` or `var is not None`.
- Try to use proper paths with os.path rather than just strings like `'/dataset/segmented_images'`. This means you can run the script from anywhere and still find the files/directories you want.
- You check `seg_dir` is not an empty string, I would be more explicit and have it either be `None` or the full path described above. Explicitly assigning something as `None` removes ambiguity. Let's say for example a path is where you are, does the path being `''` mean you've found it or not? If the path is `None` however, obviously you haven't found it.
- Frequently, your variable names are exactly the same as the keyword arguments. This is fine, except the names are often fairly non-descript: `inputs`, `filters` etc. Otherwise, variable names are quite good (concise and clear).
- You `enumerate()` over images in `load_data()` but don't use the index, just loop over it with a `for` loop.
- You don't use `glob` as an import, nor `activation` as an argument (in `trans_conv()`).
- `UNet()` would be a lot nicer with loops to remove the repeated code and unnecessary variable assignments. I would suggest one loop for pre-training and another for post.
- In `load_data()`, caching the result of `int(len(row_img) * train_val_rate` would make for much cleaner code, and would tell you what that index actually represents (with a good variable name).
- You make quite a few assumptions that the code will work as intended, far too hopeful! As an example, say you generate an empty list; on some condition you fill the list; then you assume the list has been filled and loop over it. This is fine if the condition is fulfilled, but if it's not then the program will break. Take a look at `load_data()` and consider how easy it would be to find if there was a problem with how `row_img` is (or isn't) being filled.

That's how the code *looks*; I can't really test how it *runs* without some sample data and expected in/outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your great advice. I'll fix correct the code referring to your suggestions. And I'm sorry for not puting a link of entire code, my codes are in my GitHub repository. https://github.com/Hayashi-Yudai/ML_models